# Help needed for this combinatrics problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

[image]

I got the first part but unable to understand the second part please help me

Comment: Maybe you could get a magnifying glass ... that would help.

Comment: Sometimes images can be hard to read, and they are hard (read impossible) to search for text. It also indicates a lack of effort, especially without going to the effort of saying what is giving you trouble. Please add [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and consider converting the image to text and [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you understand part (a), then you understand part (b), as it is just a repeated application of part (a). By part (a),

$R(n,r)=R(n-1,r-1)+R(n-r,r).$

By applying (a) again, we see that

$R(n-1,r-1)=R(n-2,r-2)+R(n-1-(r-1),r-1)=\\
R(n-2,r-2)+R(n-r,r-1).$

In general, we have

$R(n-k,r-k)=R(n-k-1,r-k-1)+R(n-r,r-k).$

We repeatedly apply $(a)$ until we reach $k=r-2$, so we get

$R(n,r)=R(n-r,r)+R(n-r,r-1)+R(n-r,r-2)+\cdots R(n-r,2)+R(n-r-1,1).$

For any nonnegative integer, there is only one way to partition it into one part, so $R(n-r-1,1)=1=R(n-r,1)$, hence $R(n-r)=\sum_{k-1}^r R(n-r,k)$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\color{blue}{R(n-r+1,1)} &=& R(n-r,0)+R(n-r,1) \\
\color{orange}{R(n-r+2,2)} &=& \color{blue}{R(n-r+1,1)}+R(n-r,2) \\
R(n-r+3,3) &=& \color{orange}{R(n-r+2,2)}+R(n-r,3) \\
\vdots    &= & \vdots \\
\color{blue}{R(n-1,r-1)} &=& R(n-2,r-2)+R(n-r,r-1) \\
R(n,r) &=& \color{blue}{R(n-1,r-1)}+R(n-r,r) \\
\end{eqnarray*}